# Welche Verben haben eine zweite Infinitivform mit "zu"?

Tags: verb, grammar-identification, infinitive

Mir ist soeben beim Schreiben einer Nachricht Folgendes aufgefallen:

Verb: abgewöhnen

Laut [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abgewoehnen) ist der Infinitiv abgewöhnen, aber ein zweiter Infinitiv mit "zu" ist möglich: abzugewöhnen.

[Folgende Website](https://easy-deutsch.de/satzbau/infinitiv-mit-zu/) erklärt Infinitivsätze mit "zu", doch es stellt sich mir dennoch die Frage, wie nun die genauen Grammatikregeln für Infinitivsätze mit "zu" lauten, insbesondere bei trennbaren Verben.

"Alle Verben, die sich zwingend auf eine Handlung beziehen, nutzen den Infinitiv mit zu:"

In meinem Beispiel war der Satz:

> Sorry, dass ich so oft huste. Ich werde versuchen es mir abzugewöhnen.

Woher kommt nun das "zu" in dem Verb?

Wieso ist es in folgendem Satz nicht?

> Sorry, dass ich so oft huste. Ich werde es mir abgewöhnen.

Liegt es daran, dass ein zweites Verb in dem Satz vorkommt? Gibt es eine Grammatikregel, die mir dieses Konzept genauer erklären könnte?

Die Frage stellt sich mir jetzt nicht als jemand, der Deutsch lernt. Mich würde nur die Regel interessieren, anwenden kann ich sie zum Glück automatisch.

Comment: 'aber ein zweiter Infinitiv mit "zu" ist möglich' - hast du denn auch Verben gefunden, bei denen *kein* "zweiter Infinitiv" mit "zu" "möglich" ist?

Answer (score 1):

**Infinitivregierende Verben**

Infinitive mit oder ohne *zu* lassen sich nicht beliebig mit anderen Verben zu einem Verbalkomplex (manche sagen auch *Prädikat*, andere *Verbverband*) kombinieren.

> Es gibt Verben, die sich mit einem **Infinitiv ohne *zu*** verbinden
> lassen:
> *Er **fuhr** die Kinder im Fahrradanhänger **spazieren***.
>
> Andere Verben erlauben den Anschluss eines **Infinitivs** nur **mit *zu***:
> *Sie **schien zu schlafen***.
>
> Die meisten Verben erlauben **keine Verbindung mit einem Infinitiv**: **Sie schreibt Samstag zu kommen.* Hier ist nur ein *dass*-Satz möglich: *Sie schreibt, dass sie am Samstag kommen will.*

Viele Verbindungen von (konjugiertem) **Verb + Infinitiv ohne *zu*** treten regelmäßig in bekannten grammatischen Funktionen auf, z.B. als **Futur I** (*werden + Infinitv*) oder in **Modalverb**komplexen (*er will / muss / soll / darf / kann / mag nicht / braucht nicht (zu)* + Infinitiv) oder als **würde-Konjunktiv** (*Donnerstag würde bei mir gehen*). Dein zweiter Beispielsatz ist ein solcher Satz im Futur I, welches mit *werden* und mit einem Infinitiv ohne *zu* gebildet wird.

Ob ein Verb einen Infinitivanschluss mit oder ohne *zu* erlaubt oder nicht, ist eine seiner syntaktischen Eigenschaften. Man nennt Verben, die sich mit einem abhängigen Infinitiv verbinden können, **infinitivregierende Verben**.

Eine erste Übersicht, um welche Verben es sich handelt, findet man bei [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Infinitivregierende_Verben#Gebrauch_mit_Infinitiv_+_%E2%80%9Ezu%E2%80%9C) Diese Liste ist allerdings nicht vollständig. *Versuchen* ist ein Verb, das den Infinitiv mit *zu* fordert.

**Stellung des *zu* beim Infinitiv mit *zu***

Das *zu* steht bei nicht zusammengesetzten und nicht trennbaren Verben als selbständiges Wort vor dem Infinitiv:

> nicht zusammengesetztes Verb: *Sie hat mir verboten, zu kommen.*
>
> nicht trennbares Verb: *Ich bitte Sie, das letzte zu wiederholen.*

Bei trennbaren Verben tritt das *zu* zwischen den abtrennbaren Teil und das Grundverb, wobei alle drei Elemente zusammengeschrieben werden:

> trennbares Verb: *Ich freue mich, euch wiederzusehen.*

Mit 'Trennbarkeit' ist im Falle von *wiedersehen* gemeint, dass *wieder-* sich in bestimmten syntaktischen Umgebungen vom Verb löst: *Ich hoffe, wir sehen uns bald wieder*.

Besonders interessant sind unter dem Aspekt der Trennbarkeit *wiederh**o**len* (nicht trennbar, Bedeutung "noch einmal tun/sagen") bzw. *w**ie**derholen* (trennbar, Bedeutung "zurückholen": *Ich werde mir mein Geld wiederholen*) bzw. *w**ie**der h**o**len* (zwei Wörter, Bedeutung "erneut / noch einmal holen": *Die Mannschaft hat wieder nur den zweiten Platz geholt.*) Als Infinitive mit *zu* wären das:

> nicht trennbar: *Sie forderte mich auf, das zu wiederholen.*
>
> trennbar: *Ich war entschlossen, mir das geklaute Handy wiederzuholen.*
>
> 2 Wörter: *Er bestand darauf, sich das gleiche Billighandy wieder zu holen, mit dem er so viel Ärger gehabt hatte.*

Answer (score 0):

Es gibt

- Infinitivsätze, da muss das "zu" immer vorkommen (Ich habe vor, ab**zu**reisen, Er freut sich darauf, laufen zu können). Das "zu" kommt entweder vor dem Verb, wenn das Verb untrennbar ist (übersEtzen, entlaufen usw.) oder zwischen der Vorsilbe und dem Verb, (abzurEisen).
- es gibt substantivierte Verben, wo man kein "zu" braucht (er mag das Radfahren nicht)
- es gibt schließlich Zusammensetzungen von Hauptverben und Hilfsverben/Modalverben, z.b. "ich kann schwimmen", "ich will schlafen", "er wird sich freuen", da verwendet man kein "zu". Grenzfall: das Verb brauchen, welches in der Umgangssprache schon längst ohne zu gebraucht wird, als wäre es modal.

Entscheidend ist hier die Satzstruktur, und nicht die Bedeutung eines einzelnen Verbes. Wichtig ist nur die Gegensetzung von Vollverben und Modalverben/Hilfsverben.

Comment: Fehlt in der Antwort nicht irgendwie die explizite Aussage, dass es gar nicht darum geht, welche Verben verwendet werden, sondern dass abhängig von der Satzform prinzipiell jedes Verb betroffen sein kann?

Comment: _"er mag das Radfahren nicht"_ Man könnte ebenso formulieren: Er mag es nicht (mit dem) Rad zu fahren.

Comment: Aber dann doch lieber mit dem (auch wenn optionalen) Komma, "er mag es nicht, Rad zu fahren"

Comment: @Dan   Komma: Dies umso mehr, als man sonst auch lesen könnte: "*Er mag es, nicht Rad zu fahren.*"

Comment: Der lebende Beweis für "sicher ist sicher" :)

Comment: analog zu *abzugewöhnen* und *Radfahren* wäre es wohl *radzufahren*. Frage nicht verstanden. Frage verfehlt. Das fällt mir nur auf, weil mich die Frage interessiert. Verfehlen kann ich sie zum Glück selber.